# swift - UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

I am saving a image in the camera roll. But when it is done, I should make a reference to the image in the DB. The logic is pretty simple

```
class MyDownloader{
    let db : DbHelper = DbHelper.sharedInstance

    func downloadFileFromServer(){
        let urlString = "http://any-image.jpg"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        if(image == nil){
            println("no downloaded image")
        }
        else{
            // THIS WORKS WITH NO ERRORS
            --> --> UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

            // THIS NEVER WORKS 
            --> --> UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
        }
    }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSErrorPointer, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
        if error != nil {
            // error feedback goes here
        }
        else{
            // save db reference here
        }
    }
}
```

The method below

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
```

always returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should make `MyDownloader` inherit from `NSObject` as `selector` is part of Objective-C's runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your MyDownloader class instance is probably being deallocated before the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum call finishes, so when it tries to call the image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: method, the callback target no longer exists. Make sure that your MyDownloader object sticks around.

Comment: I got it! But how can I do that? Is it possible to use a static method?

Comment: add a property -    var aDownloader : MyDownloader?    ,   then when you use it - assign it to this property which will keep it around.